# How to translate menu items?

Tags: menus, translation

Is there a way for the menu to be translated when I choose the website language? Does anyone have a solution to do it without using the plugin?

Comment: I recently wrote code which switched between two different menus depending on the language the user was browsing in. It wasn't that easy! A plugin might help, but I couldn't recommend one from experience. I know WPML is popular, might do what you need...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a menu use another language. Then you use conditional code to switch the menu. or you can use title attribute of menu.

```
if($language=='us'):
wp_nav_menu(menu1);
else:
wp_nav_menu(menu2);
endif;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use Polylang plugin which will create different template for each language, and integrate different menu for each language.

start reading here and dig in: https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple hook to use the normal translation functions, which I just added into my theme's `functions.php` file.

```
/** Translate menu items. */
function translate_menu_item_frontend($item_output, $item) {
    if (property_exists($item, 'title')) {
        $parts = explode('|', $item->title);
        $context = count($parts) > 1 ? $parts[0] : null;
        $text = end($parts);

        return preg_replace(
            '/(<.*?>).*(<\/.*?>)/s', '$1' . _x($text, $context) . '$2', $item_output, 1);
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'translate_menu_item_frontend', 20, 2);
add_filter('megamenu_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'translate_menu_item_frontend', 20, 2);
```

This means you can, for example, set a menu item navigation label to 'Home' and it will be translated with the builtin core translations. You can also specify a context separated with `|`, so for example 'Theme starter content|Contact' would use the builtin core translations for the word 'Contact'.

This can easily be adapted to support custom domains if you want to provide your own translations too.

Comment: On a related note, if you want the site to automatically change language based on the user's browser settings, I wrote a small plugin for that here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/preferred-locale/